# deallocating memory from a structure

Tags: c, memory-management

I am basically trying to de-allocate memory from a structure which had user inputted data, so the goal is to wipe the data so a new set of data can be re entered into the structure.

This is the structure

```
 struct packet{
    int source;
    int destination;
    int type;               // Varibles for the structure
    int port;
    char data[50];
    char * filename;
};
```

pointers to the structure

```
struct packet s[50];         //Array for structure input
struct packet *p_s;
p_s = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));
```

the code where user inputted data is added to the variables in the structure

```
printf("\n****Adding a packet*****\n");
printf("Where is the packet from?\n");
scanf("%i", &s[NetworkPacket].source);
printf("Where is the packet going?\n");
scanf("%i", &s[NetworkPacket].destination);
printf("What type is the packet?\n");
scanf("%i", &s[NetworkPacket].type);  // collecting the data of the packet inputted by the user
printf("What is the packet's port?\n");
scanf("%i", &s[NetworkPacket].port);
printf("Enter up to 50 characters of data.\n");
scanf("%s", s[NetworkPacket].data);
```

This is how I view the structure data

```
        printf("\n%i\nSource: %d", ii, s[ii].source);
        printf("\nDestination: %d", s[ii].destination );
        printf("\nType : %d", s[ii].type);// if statement giving the limit of 50 packets allowed to be added
        printf("\nPort : %d", s[ii].port);
        printf("\nData: %s\n---\n", s[ii].data);
```

Finally code I would like help with in terms of getting it to remove the set of user inputed data from above so a new set can be added.

```
system("cls");
free(p_s);
printf("All the data entered has been cleared. Press any key to continue");
```

Comment: In general, you only need to use `free` on something that you have previously received from `malloc`.

Comment: You only need to free struct member that you have malloc for them.

Answer (score 1):

You only need `free(p_s);`. You cannot deallocate the members one-by-one since they weren't allocated one-by-one either.

Comment: @NabilAziz: How are you viewing them?

Comment: @NabilAziz - when you deallocate the struct with `free`, it does not erase the contents of that memory location immediately; it just makes that memory available to the operating system for some other process to use. If you `free` the memory and then immediately try to print out its contents, the odds are good that you will see the data that was stored there. If another program has already claimed the memory, your program will receive a segmentation fault. Either way, once you have called `free(p_s)`, you have deallocated the memory and there is nothing more you need to do.

Comment: ok, so is there a way to basically, when i display the records after clearing it, it shows up as no records shown?

Comment: also, i output the records on a text file, and the records are still written, so it doesnt actually work for some reason

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-use the previous allocated memory. You can use memset to fill all allocated memory to '\0'. By doing this you are reseting the whole strcuture except the char* filename! This char* you need to allocate, and dellocate independent of allocating or dellocating the parent structure.

Comment: could you show me how I would put that as an example on this problem? Not sure how to use memset

Comment: Sure! With memset you can set all bytes of a buffer into a specific value.

`<br/>#define BUFFER_LEN 128<br/>
char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];<br/>
<br/>
...<br/>
memset(buffer, '\0', BUFFER_LEN);`
`